# Image edge detection Keras model loss not improving

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, keras, edge-detection

I have a video of droplets. I have taken the first frame and manually marked the edges. I split up the image into smaller images. I then tried to train a keras model of the small unmarked images against the small marked images.

I've tried using "dense" layers. The model trains, but the loss does not improve. When I try using the model, it just gives me a black image output.

Marked split images
[image]

Input image (frame 1)
[image]

Model summary
[image]

```
#################### IMPORT AND SPLIT

from cam_img_split import cam_img_split
import cv2

img_tr_in=cv2.imread('frame 1.png')
img_tr_out=cv2.imread('frame 1 so far.png')
seg_shape=[32,32]

tr_in=cam_img_split(img_tr_in,seg_shape)
tr_out=cam_img_split(img_tr_out,seg_shape)

pl=[4,20] #images selected for training

##################### NEURAL NETWORK

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import adam

b_sha=np.prod(tr_in.shape[2:5]) #batch shape

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(b_sha, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3072, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(3072, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(3072, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(np.prod(tr_out.shape[2:5]), activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer=adam(lr=0.1), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

tr_in_sel=tr_in[0:pl[0],0:pl[1],:,:,:]
tr_out_sel=tr_out[0:pl[0],0:pl[1],:,:,:]

tr_in_sel_flat=tr_in_sel.reshape([np.prod(pl),b_sha])   #Flattening
tr_out_sel_flat=tr_in_sel.reshape([np.prod(pl),b_sha])

tr_in_sel_flat_norm=tr_in_sel_flat/255
tr_out_sel_flat_norm=tr_out_sel_flat/255

model.fit(tr_in_sel_flat_norm, tr_out_sel_flat_norm, epochs=10, batch_size=pl[0])
```

I expected an output matching the images with the marked edges. Instead I got a black image output.

Comment: You should not use softmax as activation for hidden layers.

Comment: Thank you, which activation function should I be using?

Comment: Generally works out well to stick to ReLU activations, unless you have some specific transformations in mind. Also, since you're basically looking for edges, don't convolutions seem more ideal than just dense layers?

Comment: You could also use **sigmoid**, could you **print(model.summary())** ?

Comment: Thank you! I've added an image of the model summary in a link at the top.

Comment: I've applied a conv2d network to the same problem, however it is still not working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217777/conv2d-cnn-edge-detection-script-returns-blank-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I solved this problem by using 7x7 sections of the image to classify the central pixel of that section as either oil or water (1 or 0). I then used the binary_crossentropy loss function to train the model.

By having a 7x7 section moving one pixel at a time across the main image, I can have a lot more training data than just segmenting the main image.

I previously tried to get a 7x7 image from another 7x7 image, which made the problem more difficult.

```
#IMPORT AND SPLIT

from cam_img_split import cam_img_split
from cam_pad import cam_pad
from cam_img_bow import cam_img_bow
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_tr_in=cv2.imread('frame 1.png',0)[0:767,0:767]/255
img_tr_out=cv2.imread('frame 1 so far bnw 2.png',0)[0:767,0:767]/255
img_tr_out=(cam_img_bow(img_tr_out,0.5)).astype(np.uint8)

seg_shape=[15,15] #needs to be odd and equal to each other

pl_max=img_tr_in.shape[0:2]
pl=np.array([0.15*pl_max[0],pl_max[1]]).astype(np.uint32)

pad_in=int(np.floor(seg_shape[0]/2))

img_tr_in_pad=cam_pad(img_tr_in,pad_in)

tr_in=np.zeros([pl[0],pl[1],seg_shape[0],seg_shape[1]])

for n1 in range(0,pl[0]):
        for n2 in range(0,pl[1]):
                tr_in[n1,n2]=img_tr_in_pad[n1:n1+seg_shape[0],n2:n2+seg_shape[1]]


##################### NEURAL NETWORK

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import adam
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pad=4

input_shape=(seg_shape[0]+2*pad,seg_shape[1]+2*pad,1)
output_shape=(1,1,1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=adam(lr=0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


##################### FITTING THE MODEL

tr_in_flat=tr_in.reshape([pl[0]*pl[1],seg_shape[0],seg_shape[1],1])
tr_out_flat=img_tr_out.reshape([pl_max[0]*pl_max[1]])

tr_in_flat_pad=np.zeros(tr_in_flat.shape+np.array([0,2*pad,2*pad,0]))

for n3 in range(0,tr_in_flat.shape[0]):
        tr_in_flat_pad[n3,:,:,0]=cam_pad(tr_in_flat[n3,:,:,0], pad)

model.fit(tr_in_flat_pad, to_categorical(tr_out_flat[0:pl[0]*pl[1]]), epochs=5, batch_size=int(16*pl[0]),shuffle=True)


##################### PLOTTING PREDICTIONS

tr_in_full=np.zeros([pl_max[0],pl_max[1],seg_shape[0]+2*pad,seg_shape[1]+2*pad])

for n1 in range(0,pl_max[0]):
        for n2 in range(0,pl_max[1]):
                tr_in_full[n1,n2]=cam_pad(img_tr_in_pad[n1:n1+seg_shape[0],n2:n2+seg_shape[1]],pad)


tr_in_full_flat=tr_in_full.reshape([pl_max[0]*pl_max[1],seg_shape[0]+2*pad,seg_shape[1]+2*pad,1])

pred = model.predict(tr_in_full_flat)

pred_img=np.zeros(pred.shape[0])

for n1 in range(0,pred.shape[0]):
        pred_img[n1]=round(pred[n1,0])

pred_img_out=(pred_img.reshape([pl_max[0],pl_max[1]]))

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(pred_img_out)

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(img_tr_in)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong loss/metric combo. Is your problem classification, or regression? MSE is for regression, while categorical_crossentropy (or sparse, or binary) is for classification.

Comment: I am not looking to classify. I am looking to take one image and turn it into another image.